# Error while attempting to run Django-admin dbshell no module named 'myprojectname'

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

I have been trying for hours to get this error to go away but I am truly at a loss. When I run try to set the settings environment it fails. I dont know what im doing wrong here. I dont know what it means to not be able to find the module. The settings file is clearly there.

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Hyper_Web_App_Directory.settings
Django-admin runserver
```

results in this error

```
(venv) C:\Users\unblo\PycharmProjects\Hyper_Web_App_Directory>set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Hyper_Web_App_Directory.settings

(venv) C:\Users\unblo\PycharmProjects\Hyper_Web_App_Directory>Django-Admin runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\unblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Hyper_Web_App_Directory'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\unblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\unblo\PycharmProjects\Hyper_Web_App_Directory\venv\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\users\unblo\pycharmprojects\hyper_web_app_directory\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\unblo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Hyper_Web_App_Directory'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the structure of your project? It is trying to import a settings file from the Hyper_Web_App_Directory directory but not finding that directory. It could also be case sensitivity as I am seeing the directory listed as 'hyper_web_app_directory' in the traceback. Try setting the settings module to the same thing but with Hyper_Web_App_Directory all lowercase.

Comment: Looks like you're using pycharm, have you set the environment variable in pycharm?